# preload nested association query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to order by in a query preload. This is my query:

```
query =
      from(
        p in Project,
        preload: [rows: {from(r in Row, order_by: r.index), [images: from(r in Row, order_by: r.index)}]],
        where: p.user_id == ^user_id
      )
```

But this doesn't work and gives me a syntax error:

```
** (SyntaxError) web/controllers/project_controller.ex:11: "{" is missing terminator "}". unexpected token: ")" at line 13
```

Does anybody know how to preload nested attributes with Ecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive this `SyntaxError`, because the brackets are not balanced.

The following code has this problem fixed:

```
query =
  from(
    p in Project,
    preload: [rows: {from(r in Row, order_by: r.index), images: from(r in Row, order_by: r.index)}],
    where: p.user_id == ^user_id
  )
```

But actually, if you have `Project`, which `has_many` `rows` and `Row`, which `has_many` `images`, then preloading these association is going to be as simple, as this:

```
from p in Project, preload: [rows: :images]
```